# Detect an Invalid User Attribute Field entry in OIM and send email notification based on the user type

Tags: oim

I am required to create a Java Script but unable to figure on how to proceed as I don't have that much of coding idea in OIM, can someone assist(below I have mentioned the scenario)

Scenario:

1. In OIM User Attribute Page, there is a User Field: 'Job Code' now we have experienced that there are some issues we are facing.
2. From the trusted source we are getting the correct data but as soon as it reaches OIM for few users we are getting random incorrect value. Value should be numbers (123456) which is present in the Database too and valid but for few we are receiving values like E?401@q something like this.
3. We are required to place a check to find users who are having these invalid Job Code entry.
4. Once detected, we need to trigger a email to the concerned team based on the User Type (Employee or Contractor) for employee it should trigger an email to a respective team and for Contractor we have to trigger to a different team to take action.

So, I believe we have to place two conditions here, can someone assist.

Comment: What exactly is your task to solve ("work on a required and create a Java Script" is a bit unclear) ? What did you try/setup already?

Comment: OIM setup is done but we encountered few users with invalid User field: Job Code. We need to find them out everyday and trigger email to the concerned team based on their User Type (Employee or Contractor) for employee it should trigger an email to a respective team and for Contractor we have to trigger to a different team to take action.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe it only happens during trusted source reconciliation, then you can create Post-Process Handler on User Create/Modify operation to check the value which was posted into the DB as a result of recon event.

From this handler you can do all the things you need to do: mailing, fixing, etc.

For notification purposes I'd recommend to use built-in NotificationService, though it might be bit daunting, if you have little experience in OIM development. As an alternative you can do java mailing.

If you are not sure about the moment, when this "spoiling" happens, you can create a scheduled task, to be executed periodically, which will check JobCode values, to report invalid ones.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I have to check if that is happening from Trusted Source Recon(which I also feel so) or later on randomly value is changing to a strange one. If you have any sample Java Script(kind of similar or anything relatable), please share.

Comment: Start with this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMDEV/oper.htm#OMDEV4741 which has some description, as well as code examples